# Colon after background (to load background.js)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with my manifest.json for an Google Chrome extension. I want to load an script in the background. When I want to load the extension i get an syntax error, caused by the colon in line 10. I have looked in the Google Chrome Developer Documentation, but I don't find any helpfully information. Can you help me :D

```
    {
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test",
  "browser_action": {
  },
  "permissions": [["webRequest","webRequestBlocking",
                  "*://*.Test.com/*/*" ],
  **"background": {** 
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid and you really do have a syntax error. It looks like you tried to make the background part of the permissions array but here is what it should look like.

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Test",
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "*://*.Test.com/*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

Keeping your JSON well formated will often help prevent mistakes like this. Good luck with your extension.

Comment: JSON Lint (http://jsonlint.com/) is a great tool to check the validity of your JSON. Makes debugging the manifest files much easier.

Comment: @Ibykos be sure to accept the answer if it works. Glad you got it working!